# AWS EC2 (Amazon AMI Linux) ssh on Windows

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm new with AWS EC2. I've the following situation:

1. I launched AWS EC2 Micro Instance Amazon AMI Linux at the office.
2. Everything works as expected. I could login to EC2 as ec2-user without any problem using PuTTY on WIndows.
3. I then went home. It still worked fine.
4. I then stopped and started it again.
5. I tried to connect using PuTTY again. Unfortunately, it does not work anymore.
6. I used http://network-tools.com/ to get my IP address (xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx).
7. Using ASW console, I went to NETWORK&SECURITY -> Security Group. I clicked "Inbound -> Create a new rule -> SSH". xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx./32.

Unfortunately, it still does not work.
Please help.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instance will get a new IP address  when you stop and start it.

You can associate an Elastic IP Address with the instance after starting it each time if you want to use the same address to connect with it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What do I need to do to make my instance work again? Thanks again.

Comment: I went to AWS Console -> INSTANCES -> Instances. Click the instance. It shows the details of the instances at lower pane window. I notice the "Public DNS" name has changed. I use this new name on PuTTY. Now it works! THANK YOU!

Comment: For me the easiest thing to do is assign an elastic ip address to the instance and then save that ip address in putty with the associated auth key you used to create the instance. When you stop/start the instance, just rebind it to the elastic ip address and then your putty entry will continue to work unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

u must use the public dns or public ip (associate the elastic ip to your instance.) By default the ssh 22 port opened.Jus use ssh -i private key file ec2-user@public ip to connect your remote server-an instance in amazon aws.